# Executing tool comes back with an error arcpy.JoinField_management

Tags: arcpy

I have this script snippet, written by Aaron.

```
import arcpy
import os

#set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Wetland\\New_Folder" #in the folder "New_Folder" is a geodatabase which contains all the shapefiles
ws = arcpy.env.workspace

#create a list of features
fcl = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#loop through the list
for fc in fcl:
    basename = fcl.split("_")[0] #split name of features and only take the first word as a basename


    in_data = os.path.join(ws, basename + "_clip_diss.shp") #The table or feature class to which the join table will be joined.
    in_field = "WLType" #The field in the input table on which the join will be based.
    join_table = os.path.join(ws, basename + "_clip_full.shp") #The table to be joined to the input table.
    join_field = "WLType" #The field in the join table that contains the values on which the join will be based.
    fieldList = ["area_ha"]


arcpy.JoinField_management(in_data , in_field , join_table , join_field, fieldList) 
#JoinField_management (in_data, in_field, join_table, join_field, {fields})
```

It does not come back with an error message, but it does not do the join neither. It runs but there is no result. No join.

Comment: It shouldn't scare you as it's likely a syntax error. Are you sure the inputs you are passing to JoinField() exist are and valid? Print all the variables you are using and see if they make sense as inputs.

Comment: Oh thank god. I thought my arcpy code would be destroyed or something...
i added a screen of the data going in.
Just realised that what I did (appending the screen) does not make any sense at all. I check the inputs etc. and come back when I know more!

Comment: Alright. Something unexpected. I base the Join on the WLtype but it seems that some Attributetables I want to join do not have the same lenghts. Some have 4 rows, others 2 - depening on the amount of different WLtypes. Of course that cant work... Is there a way to tell the script to only add the matching WLTypes and get rid of the rest?

Comment: If the fields don't perfectly match, it should skip.

Comment: Automatically or do I have to add it

Comment: There aren't any more parameters to use. Before going any further, you should pick different tables in your folder and see what happens when you do a manual join. When you understand how JoinFields() works, then you can return to your code and edit as needed.

Comment: I did already a couple of manual joins which work perfectly. In the manual option you can tick `to only keep the matching values`.
That again is only available for the `Join`, not for the `JoinField`. But looking into the Help/Manual of `AddJoin` it does not say how to add this option to the Python Code. It does not matter for the sake of the project weather I `AddJoin` or `JoinField`. But it seems that this option of skipping if not matching does not exist (looking at this `http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000064000000`)

Comment: I am getting there. Sorry for my to early reply. It feels like I am totally lost in python. I am working on it. Thanks for dealing with my crap!

Comment: If anyone stumbles across that problem: I had to convert all my shapefiles into a geodatabase and set the path new to that geodatabase.

Comment: If your {fields} parameter is empty, no fields will be joined...

Comment: Ah, alright. I edited my post with the new parameter. Its "processing" now, but it comes up with an error message: `RuntimeError: Not Initialized`. Then it points to this line. `def _refresh(self): envset = (set(env for env in self._gp.listEnvironments()))`

Comment: Managed to get rid of that RuntimeError Message. There was something wrong with the licence. But it is still not excecuting...Nothing happens

Comment: Can you make sure that the `WLType` fields in both `in_data` and `join_table` are of the same data type and that there are matching values?

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 issues in you script:

1. You're missing the second `join_field` parameter in `arcpy.JoinField_management`. Refer to the [tool's page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Join_Field/001700000065000000/) for the correct syntax: `JoinField_management (in_data, in_field, join_table, join_field, {fields})`
2. If you work with shapefiles and dbf tables, you should add the .shp or .dbf extension to your inputs. For example your inFeatures will be: `C:\\Users\\Documents\\Wetland\\<basename>_clip_diss`, which doesn't exist. This of course is not necessary if you work with gdb feature classes and tables.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply! I tried to add the .shp already - that did not solve the problem. But I cannot see which parameter I am missing. Four are needed, and I add four. The `input_Data` is `InFeatures`, the `in_field` is `joinField`, the `join_table` is the `jointable` and the `join_field` is the `fieldList` variable?

Comment: `join_field` must be a **field**, not a list of fields. It is the field from the `join_table` used to join it to `in_data`, while `{fields}` is the **list of fields** from `join_table` to be joined to `in_data`.

Comment: I edited my post!